# How to rasterize a batch of polygons in python

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, polygon, rasterizing

I have a batch of polygons which could be a NumPy array, torch tensor, or any other nd-array of shape `(230_000, 3, 2)`. `230_000` is the number of polygons, `3` indicates it's a triangle, `2` is its x and y coordinates.

I also have a batch of features of shape `(230_000, 3, 3)` (last is the color), it's best the color of the features are interpolated during rasterization.

I am trying to find a way to rasterize all of them such that the output looks something like this:

[image: Polygon Rasterization]

There are not many rules to the algorithm. what is most important is filled polygons rasterized on an `ndarray` and is fast. the batch size will be hundreds of thousands of polygons. for loops will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on creating a raster with python, I would check out Rasterio. If your main goal is to create the above visualization with Python, an easier way to go about it would be to use shapely and matplotlib. It also seems like your potentially missing a piece--you also need a function that generates shapes. You mention:

> 230_000 is the number of polygons, 3 indicates it's a triangle, 2 is its x and y coordinates

2 is the x and y coordinates of what point? more information is necessary to understand the type of shapes you need to generate.

AFAIK, what you need to do is:

- iterate yours arrays (no way around it)
- define a function that takes an individual array and returns a shapely polygon from the supplied inputs https://autogis-site.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/L1/geometric-objects.html
  From there I would:
- convert to a geopandas dataframe https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/geodataframe.html
- convert the GeoDataFrame to GeoJSON https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_json.html
- pass the geojson to rasterio https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html

Comment: For clarification, let's suppose batch of [1,4,2], if we take polygons at index 0 (polygons[0]) we end with shape [4,2], polygons[0,0] indicates the first point of the first index of the batch. polygons[0,0,1] is the y axis of the first point of polygons[0]. because the batch holds 4 points. a quadrilateral gets rasterized. polygons[0,0] is first order, polygons[0,1] is the second order of points for polygons[0]. It's really just polygon rasterization but in batches.

Answer (score 0):

I did ending up figuring out a method to do it in pytorch. It's not fast but it works.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import cv2

class TriRasterizer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,shape=(480,640),channels:int=3,_trainable=False):
        super(TriRasterizer, self).__init__()
        assert len(shape) == 2
        self._shape = shape
        self._backdrop = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(*shape,channels,dtype=torch.float),requires_grad=_trainable)
        # Feel free to mess around with the quality
        self.quality = 0.1
        ...

    @staticmethod
    @torch.jit.script
    def _fill(poly,area,_type:torch.dtype=torch.float32):
        """
        The main part
        The algorithm takes the tensor points, repeats interleave them by their area
        Then for each tiangles in the batch:
            there should be the-area more triangles exactly the same
            the goal is for each of those extra triangles,
                interpolate each of those points such that: each points fills up the traingle

        """
        # calculate center of the base
        base_p = (poly[:,0] + poly[:,1])/2
        a_diff = (poly[:,2]-base_p) . detach()

        # then height
        heights = torch.sqrt_(torch.square_(a_diff[...,0]) + torch.square_(a_diff[...,1]))

        # comulative sum of the areas
        # This gives positional embeding for each points when subtracted from torch.arange
        cum   = torch.cumsum(area,dim=0).int()
        poly  = poly.type(_type)
        heights  = heights.type(torch.int16)
        poly    = poly.repeat_interleave(area,dim=0)
        cum_    = cum.repeat_interleave(area,dim=0)
        heights = heights.repeat_interleave(area,dim=0)

        # normalized makes the first point = 0 and last = 1 for the repeated points
        normalized = 1-(cum_-torch.arange(len(cum_)))/cum_

        # this is the exponential, it reduces pixels as it gets closer to the tip of the triangle
        exp = 1-torch.sqrt_(1-normalized)
        exp = exp.type(torch.float32)

        # This iterpolates more of the x as it gets to the tip of the triangle
        ij__interp = (exp % (torch.tensor(1,dtype=torch.float16)/heights))[...,None]
        # * heights[...,None] just brings the exponentials max back to 1
        # the random normal washes the points and makes it appear blurry
        ij_interp = ij__interp*heights[...,None] #+ torch.randn_like(ij__interp)/70

        # this makes the makes the c interpolation exponentialy faster
        k_interp = (exp[...,None] - ij__interp)  #+ torch.randn_like(ij__interp)/70

        # Finally interpolate them
        # weigh a and b first with respect to the calculated exponential
        ij_trunc = poly[:,0] * (1-ij_interp) + poly[:,1]*ij_interp
        # then weigh the output with c with respect to the modulus of the exponential
        filled   = poly[:,2] * k_interp  + ij_trunc * (1-k_interp)
        return filled

    def _compute_area(self,poly):
        # Formula to find area from a set of points
        area = torch.abs(0.5 * ((poly[..., 0, 0] * (poly[..., 1, 1] - poly[..., 2, 1])) +
                   (poly[...,1,0]*(poly[...,2,1]-poly[...,0,1])) +
                   (poly[...,2,0]*(poly[...,0,1]-poly[...,1,1]))))
        return area

    def forward(self,traingles,features):
        return self.rasterize(traingles,features)


    @torch.no_grad()
    def rasterize(self,traingles,features):
        raster = self._backdrop.clone()
        # first find the area
        # the lower the quality the more spaces in between pixels
        area = (self._compute_area(traingles)*self.quality).int()

        # fill in points based on computed area
        filled_cords = self._fill(traingles,area,_type=torch.int16)
        filled_cords = filled_cords.long()

        # clamp the points to prevent out of bounds exception
        filled_cords[...,0] = filled_cords[...,0].clamp(min=0,max=self._shape[1]-1)
        filled_cords[...,1] = filled_cords[...,1].clamp(min=0,max=self._shape[0]-1)

        # also fill in features based on computed area
        filled_feats = self._fill(features,area,_type=torch.float32)
        pixels = (filled_cords[...,1],filled_cords[...,0])

        # compute the times the same point has been placed on the raster
        sum_ = torch.zeros_like(raster).index_put(pixels,torch.ones_like(filled_feats),accumulate=True)

        # rasterize them using indexing
        raster = raster.index_put(pixels,filled_feats,accumulate=False)

        # average those sums
        raster = raster/sum_
        return raster
#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tiangles = torch.tensor([
        [[100, 0], [0, 200], [20, 300]]
    ], dtype=torch.float) + 100

    print(tiangles.shape)
    tiangles = tiangles.expand(3,-1,-1).clone()

    features = torch.randn(*tiangles.shape[:-1], 3)
    rasterizer = TriRasterizer()
    j = torch.zeros(*tiangles.shape)

    while True:
        features = features*0.01 + torch.randn(*tiangles.shape[:-1], 3)*0.09
        j += torch.randn(*tiangles.shape)*0.1
        tiangles += j
        raster = rasterizer(tiangles,features+1)
        cv2.imshow('x',raster.numpy())
        cv2.waitKey(20)
```

I also found out other ways like binding C++ or PyOpengl